# How to convert a cmake project into a Visual Studio equivalent?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cmake

The situation is the following: I have the source code of one programm (lets call it programA) (written in C and C++), as well as the CMakeLists.txt and CTestConfig.cmake files. I already installed programA using CMake's graphical user interface and, as it is obvious, it worked. It created the .exe file (I'm working on Windows 7 OS).

The problem is that, right now, I've been asked to edit the program (and so, I must be able to edit the code and degugging it as changes are made). I also need to compile it but not in .exe anymore but in .dll so I can add it to a website we have.

I've read in forums that CMake can compile programA into a .dll if I need to, but as I would need to make some changes I consider that CMake debugging is not as useful and easy as using entirely VS. From the little I know from CMake language, the CMakeLists.txt is mainly used to check the OS of the user as well as adding some libraries in case they are not found.

I have to admit I have no idea in programming CMake directives, as I have been working with ASP.NET, C, C++ and C# mostly. Then, my idea is to try to work only in visual studio 2010 instead of using cmake as well, so once I have the program 'adapted' to VS and can be compiled just using VS, I'm ready to start my job. So the question I have is how can I perform the same task CMake did just using Visual Studio (Is there any way of implementing CMake directives in VS?), can VS compile by receiving as an argument something similar to that CMake.txt file (though it needs to be translated into another language)?

To skip the use of CMake I tried to copy the source code into a new project in VS. However as it does not use the CMake directives when compiling, it gives several errors, most of them related to the fact that some headers.h can't be found (cause they might be in a subfolder). And there are so many subfolders to add the paths to the predefined directories of search that it would take ages.

I'm sorry I can't be more precise in my explanation. I'm good at programming little projects on my own, but it's the first time I have to work on other's programm. Please don't hesitate to ask if anything was not properly understood

I would appreciate a lot any suggestion / advice /guidance you can give.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make a dll, use add_library command and the SHARED keyword

```
add_library(mylib SHARED ${files})
```

this is easy with CMake, don't go back in visual that will be harder at the end

Answer (score 1):

**The Good News**

Fortunately, [`cmake` can generate VS Projects automaticaly for you](http://www.opentissue.org/mediawiki/index.php/Using_CMake#Running_CMake_on_Windows) (this tutorial s specific for OpenTissue, but Steps 1 to 3 should be the same for you).

**The [not so] Bad News**

Depending on the complexity of the project, VS Projects automaticaly generated by `cmake` can get pretty nasty, to the point of illegibility. It will, for example, hard link any library dependencies using the specific paths of your machine, so the project will most certainly not be portable across setups. In any case, that's the intended bahavior, because the primary idea of supporting this generator is simply making it work, thus allowing users to easily compile projects using MSVC, so there's not much you can do here. Nonetheless, it should work in your machine and will certainly be a great starting point for you, just create a project yourself from scratch copying the relevant parts out of the automatic generated version.

Comment: thank you very much for your response. I will read the similar question you posted and see if I can start from all this information

Comment: Link in the answer is not available anymore, I believe same steps are specified here - https://github.com/erleben/OpenTissue/blob/master/documentation/using_cmake.md#running-cmake-on-windows